# How to write $P(\omega_{n} \neq 1| \omega_{n-1} \neq 1)$ in terms of the stochastic matrix $P$ of a Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Suppose we have a Markov chain with finite state space $X = \{1, \cdots, r \}$ and stochastic matrix $P = (p_{ij})$ with initial distribution $\pi$ which is also stable.

How does one express the conditional probability $\textbf{P}(\omega_{n} \neq 1| \omega_{n-1} \neq 1)$ in terms of $P$?

Comment: It can't be done; you need a distribution on the rest of the state space at time $n-1$.

Comment: @Ian thank you, I forgot to add that part.

Comment: Is it initially in equilibrium, or is $\pi$ just some initial distribution?

Comment: Let's just assume that $\pi$ is in equilibrium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the total probability formula to force the condition to be $\omega_{n-1}=i$:

$$P(\omega_n \neq 1 \mid \omega_{n-1} \neq 1)=\sum_{i \neq 1} P(\omega_n \neq 1 \mid \omega_{n-1}=i) P(\omega_{n-1}=i \mid \omega_{n-1} \neq 1).$$

Now for the first factor you can just expand the event $\{ \omega_n \neq 1 \}$ into the disjoint union $\bigcup_{j \neq 1} \{ \omega_n=j \}$.

For the second factor, you can use the knowledge that the chain is in equilibrium to evaluate the prior probability that $P(\omega_{n-1}=i)$ and then update it based on knowing that $\omega_{n-1} \neq 1$. So that results in $\frac{\pi_i}{1-\pi_1}$.

Comment: I'm confused about what this means in terms of the entries of the matrix.

Comment: @user135520 The first factor is transparently related to $p_{ij}$. The second factor is related to $\pi$.

Comment: @JPMcCarthy That makes no sense: $p_{i1}$ is the probability to go from $i$ to $1$, and you must know how likely it was to be at $i$ at the previous time step in the first place to know how much to weigh that possibility.

Comment: Should the first factor should be $\sum^{r}_{j \neq 1} p_{ij}$ ?

Comment: @user135520 $p_{ij}$, but otherwise yes, that's right.

Comment: Yeah, the way I was thinking was making each $i$ equally likely which is nonsense indeed, thank you.